# Spring Hibernate MySQL Unidirectional ManyToOne

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two (very simple) entities: Parent and Child.

```
@Entity
class Child {

@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
private UUID id;

@Column(columnDefinition="varchar(4000)")
private String obs;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Parent parent;

(getters and setters)
}
```

The original obs field had no annotation, so Hibernate created it as a varchar(255), but I needed it to be able to handle a larger text. After the changes (as shown above), the method getParent() always returns null.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Actually, the error happens only if the length is 1537 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

For your `Column` annotation, rather than using `columnDefinition` set the [`length`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/Column.html#length--) element. Here is the Javadoc of `length`:

> (Optional) The column length. (Applies only if a string-valued column is used.)
>
> Default:
>
> 255

You can also see why it defaulted to `VARCHAR(255)` in your schema: the default is 255. Why your `columnDefinition` doesn't work, however, I don't know (I've no experience with it).

Comment: Hello, @Slaw. I made the changes but the problem persists. I checked the queries from hibernate log and they are ok. It seems to be some issue on hibernate proxy and/or spring data jpa repository. :(
In fact, from a certain size of text, the problem begins to happen.

Comment: @MichelFortes I wouldn't consider myself an expert in JPA/Hibernate/SQL so I'm not sure I can help you further. Did you have Hibernate rebuild the schema or is it still using the old generated schema?

Comment: Yes and no, respectively. I dropped the table and hibernate created it again correctly. Even if I copy the query  and past it on mysql client it is processed correctly. I believe the problem is happening in the JPA or Spring layer.