# Unilateral ManyToOne child, with a @Lob String field, returns a null parent

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

[Link to Github](https://github.com/MichelFortes/spring-orm-lob-bug)

The parent entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="paciente")
public class Paciente {
    @Id 
    @Column(name="id", nullable=false, updatable=false, columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID id;
    (...)
}
```

And the child entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "avaliacao_clinica")
public class AvaliacaoClinica {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id", nullable=false, updatable=false, columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID id;
    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    private Paciente paciente;
    @Lob
    private String obs;
(..)
}
```

This is an unidirectional many to one relationship.
The obs field used to have no annotation but I needed it to be a Lob. After the change was made, the reference to the parent is always null.

This is the hibernate config on spring ecosystem:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {  

    String datasourceName = null;
    String debug = null;

    switch (ApplicationConstrains.ENVIROMENT) {

        case DEVELOPMENT:
            datasourceName = "jdbc/vet_dev";
            debug = "true";
            break;

        case PRODUCTION:
            datasourceName = "jdbc/vet_production";
            debug = "false";
            break;
    }

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "update");
    properties.setProperty(Environment.STORAGE_ENGINE, "innodb");
    properties.setProperty(Environment.JDBC_TIME_ZONE, "UTC");
    properties.setProperty(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect");
    properties.setProperty(Environment.SHOW_SQL, debug);
    properties.setProperty(Environment.FORMAT_SQL, debug);
    properties.setProperty(Environment.USE_SQL_COMMENTS, debug);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    factoryBean.setDataSource(new JndiDataSourceLookup().getDataSource(datasourceName));
    factoryBean.setJpaProperties(properties);
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(Paciente.class.getPackage().getName());

    return factoryBean;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {

    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setValidateExistingTransaction(true);
    txManager.setRollbackOnCommitFailure(true);
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

    return txManager;
}
```

Comment: I have never seen @Lob annotation for String type. It is generally used for the storage of file with type as byte array. Can you please check this first of all

Comment: Hello, @GarimaGupta. You can find some reference here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.2/api/javax/persistence/Lob.html.
I have absolutety no ideia whats going on. :(

Comment: What does the HibernateConfig have to do with anything? If nobody answered the question the first time (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50971806/spring-hibernate-mysql-unidirectional-manytoone), you probably need to research more, trying things yourself, and post something you have tried.

Comment: @K.Nicholas, in fact the problem does not seem to be from hibernate. I created a new project with hibernate only and everything went well. Looks like it's Spring.
I'm still investigating. I'll put any findings here. Thank you!

Comment: Good stuff. It's much easier to help you when the questions are clear and straightforward.